# Executar um vídeo em html5 em tela cheia

Tags: android, html5, webview

Estou utilizando [esta solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628513/web-view-fragment-html-embeed-video-fullscreen-suport) para carregar um html que possui um js que carrega uma url de um video criptografada.
Tudo anda muito bem porém, necessito que ao dar o primeiro play no vídeo (clicar no webview) o vídeo seja executado em fullscreen imediatamente. É possível?

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
<video controls id="myvideo">
  <source src="somevideo.webm"></source>
  <source src="somevideo.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Em javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Comment: tentei já esta solução conforme pesquisa nos fóruns e não funciona. Me retorna um aviso onde somente poderá ficar em fullscreen se tiver ações do usuário e não pelo programa/ comandos.
O estranho que no iOS ao darum play em um vídeo o  webview permite estar em tela cheia logo de ínicio e no android não. Uma tentativa que gostaria de realizar e não sei como era chamar o onShowCustomView ao dar o play no vídeo já que ele controla o frame de fullscreen.